# How to reference Fn::Transform in Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to write a transform macro within cloudformation which will format a given string into an S3 bucket name prefix. I wrote out the script as a lambda and created the macro, but I get an error saying that my transform macro name does not exist.

```
BucketNameFormattingMacro: 
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Macro
  Properties: 
    Description: Changes strings to be formatted properly to be added to S3 bucket names.
    FunctionName: !GetAtt BucketNameFormattingScript.Arn

TransformFunctionPermissions:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
    FunctionName: !GetAtt BucketNameFormattingScript.Arn
    Principal: 'cloudformation.amazonaws.com'

Bucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    BucketName:
      Fn::Transform:
        - Name: BucketNameFormattingMacro
          Parameters:
            InputString: !Sub '{ENV}-bucket'
```

Running the script throws this:

> "No transform named 699790013825::BucketNameFormattingMacro found.. Rollback requested by user."

There is a string of numbers before the name of the macro that I didn't put there that I suspect is part of the issue. Why are those numbers there and how do I properly reference the transform to use it within my bucket name?

Edit: Unfortunately, you can't access a macro within a cloudformation script if it's being created within the same script.

Comment: Are you creating the macro in the same template that you're trying to use it in? If so that won't work. If not then split that code block to show what's where.

Comment: I am creating it in the same template. If that doesn't work, then I'll just have to work around it. Thanks!

Comment: A macro transformation on a template occurs before anything else. Before any resources are created, before any template processing (resolving `!Sub` etc). So it must exist before a template can use it.

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you fixed it?